# Angular 10 Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10

I'm trying to invoke my REST API to get some data and display them in html page Using Angular 10.
here's my my http service.

```js
public findUsers(page: number, size: number): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get<User[]>(AUTH_API+`users?page=${page}&size=${size}`, httpOptions);
}
```

And here's my service's call.

```js
  export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
  paginator: MatPaginator = {} as MatPaginator;
  loaded: boolean;
  users: User[];
  data:any;

  constructor(private accountSerive: AccountService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
        this.paginator.pageSize = 20;
    this.getUsers();
  }
  getUsers() {
    this.data = this.accountSerive.findUsers(this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data;
      this.loaded = true; 
    });
  }

}
```

Here's my HTML code

```html
<tr *ngFor="let user of users" >
  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
  <td>{{user.username}}</td>
  <td>{{user.email}}</td>
  <td>{{user.password}}</td>
  <td>{{user.role}}</td>
</tr>
```

And finally my user Model

```js
    export interface User {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    userName: string;
    roles: [Role]; 

}
export interface Role {
    name: string; 
    
}
```

Here the data content [image]

Comment: It appears `this.users` isn't an array. Do a `console.log(data)` inside the subscription and post the screenshot.

Comment: Or you don't have differences for all arrays. Just add some identifiable keywords to each objects.

Comment: console.log(data) => {content: Array(5), totalElements: 5}
content: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/angular-why-doesn-t-my-data-show-up-4efm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you receive from the API apparently is returned in this format:

```js
{
  content: User[],
  totalElements: number
}
```

So the actual array of results can be found under a property called `content`.
So you need to map your call to this property like this:

```js
// return type
export interface UsersDto {
  content: User[];
  totalElements: number;
}

public findUsers(page: number, size: number): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<UsersDto>(AUTH_API+`users?page=${page}&size=${size}`, httpOptions)
             .pipe(map(result => result.content));
}
```

Comment: content is not declared any where !

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the correct return value from the endpoint